# NSInvocationOperation to call method that downloads XML file to store locally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

new to the Objective-C/iOS scene. Experienced in PHP and C++.

I'm having a little trouble using NSInvocationOperation. Here's my situation:

With some help online, I've a class, getData.h where getData.m contains:

```
#import "getData.h"

@implementation getData

@synthesize allData;

-(void)loadData{
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                                         selector:@selector(getXML) object:nil];

[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
}


-(void)getXML{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tubeupdates.com/rss/all.xml"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
if (response == nil) {
    // Check for problems
    if (requestError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
        }
    }  
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
if (allData)
    [allData appendData:data];
else 
    allData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"feed.xml"];
NSString *fullFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,fullName];
[allData writeToFile:fullFilePath atomically:YES];
}

-(void)dealloc{
[allData release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I know that the method is being called into the queue as I had made a temporary "printthis" method for it to call which simply displayed some text with NSLog. However my issue arises when trying to call the getXML function (to copy the XML file from the server). getXML works if I call it directly, but doesn't when I add it to the Queue. It's very likely that I'm missing the bigger picture and that I haven't fully understood everything before I've started. I would appreciate some help on this. It seems no matter how good you are at C++, PHP etc, iOS Programming is a tough one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getXML` you are doing a synchronous request, meaning that when the method returns, the entire data for the the request will be in your `response` NSData variable. Instead of waiting for the connection to finish loading with the delegate method, the `sendSynchronousRequest` blocks and returns when the request is finished. Likewise your `didReceiveData` delegate method will never get called.

So to solve your problem, simply take your completion logic that is in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method currently, and move it to the `getXML` method after the synchronous call returns.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've moved the logic from `connectionDidFinishLoading` method into `getXML` (within the `else` statement after error checking, not added in the above code). After running, the file was not created. What am I to do with the logic inside the `didReceiveData` method?

Comment: Right, I've just understood properly. I have to include it inside getXML use the `response` variable in place of `data`. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I'm also new to Stack Overflow!